# Rails how to rescue from a Error R15 from Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, error-handling

I have a small web application and when I upload a handful of large images I get `Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)` message from Heroku and displays my errors 500 page.

I want to be able to rescue gracefully from this error and then show the homepage.

any ideas?

Comment: Use a bigger dyno, or scale the images client-side in JavaScript before uploading them.

Comment: Thanks that is probably what I will have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `R15` error comes from a level above your application - you won't be able to handle it in the Rails app. Unless you can reduce the amount of memory the app uses, there's not much you can do, short of using a dyno with more RAM.